# Azure Web App unavailable after pay-as-you-go card expiry

Tags: azure, web, subscription

the credit card on my subscription expired and the account was disabled. A new credit card has been provided but the site is still unavailable.

How long does it take for the site to be reactivated?

Is there a way to lodge a technical support request without paying for a support contract?

thanks
Baz

Comment: This is unfortunately off-topic for Stack Overflow, as it's tied directly to billing/pricing. Please open a billing support ticket to discuss this.

Answer (score 0):

It should take up to 24 hours (but usually it takes less than 12). Also it is probable that you can reactivate [your account manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/subscription-disabled#the-subscription-was-accidentally-canceled).

To get technical support, just go to the [support page](https://portal.azure.com/?#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer, especially given that the question itself is off-topic (service/pricing support).